# HTML table column not long enough

Tags: html

I have a script that generates a table with two 'TR'. The rows are generated (with rails) based on data but the length of the 'TD's will rarely be the same. This leaves a gap of missing TD's on either side which throws off the the style. Is there a way to make the table appear complete with missing cells using css **without** javascript?

http://jsfiddle.net/e8hraszk/1/

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate using jsFiddle?

Comment: @ericbelldesigns - I think to over-simplify he means that each `<tr>` has a different number of `<td>` and it's causing gaps.

Comment: It would be easier with a jsFiddle, but assuming Mr. Llama is correct, you can use colspan to make up for the 'missing' columns: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is not a table, it's two lists.

You should not use a `<table>` element.

Since you didn't give context or code, it's hard to determine what kind of element you *do* need, but it's not a `<table>`.